# How to apply a background only for the drawable portion of a textview in Android?

Tags: android, textview, android-drawable

I have a textview in a layout which has drawable set (leftDrawable). I would like to have a background applied to only the drawable portion and the text should appear outside of the background. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could try a Layer List with a Shape Drawable as a background.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

For example, in your layout you could have a `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left"
    android:text="Hello world!" />
```

The drawable references `drawable/left.xml` which contains your layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</layer-list>
```

The icon to display can be any drawable, here the launcher icon for test purposes. The background drawable is defined in `drawable/background.xml`, which contains a shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size
        android:height="48dp"
        android:width="48dp" />
    <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

Your background doesn't have to be a shape of course, it can be any other drawable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  How will I make left.xml generic enough so that I can reuse it for different text views with different images that require a background? I need a style which can be applied that would provide a background for the image part only in a text view?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with my answer. In my example left.xml is a wrapper for your drawable, you need a new wrapper for each drawable you want to apply the background to, you wouldn't call it left.xml of course but something like yourDrawableWrapper.xml. You can reuse the background.xml of course.

Comment: You could also not use drawableLeft at all, but a separate ImageView to display your drawable and arrange it in your layout to have the same effect, then you could apply a background just to your ImageView and put it into a style if you like. Let me know if you want to explore this and I'll write up another answer.

Comment: I have up-voted your first answer. Your answer was detailed and to the point.  I am, however, considering, using a custom view extending a TextView which would programatically apply the background to just the drawable portion as this makes it re-usable.